# How to merge a `pandas` DataFrame and a `numpy` array into H5

Tags: python, pandas, h5py

I wish to yield a H5 file `file.h5` which contains both a `pandas` DataFrame and a `numpy` array.

To exemplify, say we have array `array` and DataFrame `df` defined as:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

array = np.array([0,1])
data  = {'col': [2,3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I can output array and DataFrame to separate H5 files using:

```
import h5py

f = h5py.File('array.h5', 'w')
f.create_dataset(name='my_array',
                 shape=array.shape,
                 dtype=array.dtype,
                 data=array)

df.to_hdf('dataframe.h5')
```

**Questions**

1. How can I merge `array.h5` or `dataframe.h5` into `file.h5`?
2. How can I merge `array` and `df` into a structure that is outputable to H5 format?

Comment: You could just add the array as a new column and then write to `.h5` file: `df['array'] = pd.Series(array)`

Comment: `h5py` writes and reads `numpy` arrays.  `df.to_hdf` uses  (I think) `pytables` and some sort of `Store` module.  I haven't worked with it much myself, but I think the `df` store can be read with `h5py`, though it's a complicated `group`, with the `df.values` and row/column index arrays.

Comment: You should be able to do the `to_hdf` to a file, and then open the file with `h5py` using append mode.  Then write the array dataset.  But I don't know enough about the pandas `hdf` to know how the load will go.  Another thought is to put the array in a pandas Series (if it's 1d) and save that.

Comment: It might be worth your while looking at `dataframe.h5` with `h5py` (or with `h5dump`), so get an idea of that group/dataset layout it uses.

Comment: The final goal is to have a single H5 with various `numpy` tensors and `DataFrames` containing corresponding metadata, which is why I can't add the array to dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want. I do not know if it is possible. But you can write the array, dataframe in the same file. But it is loosing the column index name for dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import h5py

np_array = np.array([0, 1])
data = {'col': [2, 3, 4], 'col2': [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

with h5py.File("my_test_file.h5", 'w') as hf:
    hf.create_dataset("numpy_db", data=np_array)
    hf.create_dataset("pd_db", data=df)

with h5py.File('my_test_file.h5', 'r') as hf:
    np_db = hf['numpy_db'][:]
    pd_db = hf['pd_db'][:]
### But you will loose the column index name
pd_db = pd.DataFrame(pd_db)
np_db
```

Comment: `h5py` saves an array.  If given a dataframe, it will convert it to an array first.  That I think is equivalent to saving `df.values` or `df.to_numpy()`.  That should work fine if the dataframe just has numeric values, but any column dtype is `object` (e.g. strings), it probably will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [134]: array = np.array([0,1]) 
     ...: data  = {'col': [2,3, 4]} 
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)                                                                  
In [135]: import h5py                                                                                        
In [136]: df                                                                                                 
Out[136]: 
   col
0    2
1    3
2    4

In [138]: sf = pd.Series(array)                                                                              
In [139]: sf                                                                                                 
Out[139]: 
0    0
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Writing the pandas objects to file:

```
In [141]: df.to_hdf('dataframe.h5',key='df')                                                                 
In [142]: sf.to_hdf('dataframe.h5',key='sf',mode='a')
```

Opening the file with `h5py`:

```
In [144]: f = h5py.File('dataframe.h5', 'a')                                                                 
In [145]: list(f.keys())                                                                                     
Out[145]: ['df', 'sf']
In [146]: list(f['df'].keys())                                                                               
Out[146]: ['axis0', 'axis1', 'block0_items', 'block0_values']
In [147]: list(f['sf'].keys())                                                                               
Out[147]: ['index', 'values']
In [148]: f['sf/values'][:]                                                                                  
Out[148]: array([0, 1])           # the series is easy to read
```

Writing the array to a dataset:

```
In [149]: f.create_dataset(name='myarray',data=array)                                                        
Out[149]: <HDF5 dataset "myarray": shape (2,), type "<i8">
In [150]: list(f.keys())                                                                                     
Out[150]: ['df', 'myarray', 'sf']
In [151]: f.close()
```

I can read the two pandas groups:

```
In [154]: pd.read_hdf('dataframe.h5', key='df')                                                              
Out[154]: 
   col
0    2
1    3
2    4
In [155]: pd.read_hdf('dataframe.h5', key='sf')                                                              
Out[155]: 
0    0
1    1
dtype: int64
```

`pd.read_hdf` can't handle `myarray`.

In the shell I can look at the file with `h5dump` or

```
1230:~/mypy$ h5ls dataframe.h5
df                       Group
myarray                  Dataset {2}
sf                       Group
```