# When using Pandas to_hdf is it possible to specify a column data type to vlen special_dtype / vlarray for ragged tensors?

Tags: pandas, numpy, hdf5, h5py, pytables

I have a Pandas column which contains numpy arrays or lists of varying size. If I try to convert the dataframe to hdf5 using to_hdf , I get the message that says

```
PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed-integer,key->block0_values]
```

I am guessing this because of the ragged tensors in pandas column. HDpy does have a special datatype for ragged tensors.

http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/special.html#arbitrary-vlen-data

Example here

```
h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=np.dtype('int32'))
h5f.create_dataset('batch', data=yourData, dtype=dt, compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)
```

So I can convert the pandas df to numpy, and then save each numpy array separately, with the varying length column stored with the special vlen datatype.

I am wondering if there is a way to do this in Pandas.

The following is a minimal example using a small chunk of my data. It downloads and opens a small chunk of the dataframe, and saves it to hdf5

```
import requests
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Download function for google drive 

def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)

    if token:
        params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
        response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)    

def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value

    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

#download the google drive file 
download_file_from_google_drive('1-0R28Yhdrq2QWQ-4MXHIZUdZG2WZK2qR', 'sample.pkl') 

sampleDF2 = pd.read_pickle('sample.pkl')

sampleDF2.to_hdf( 'pandasList.hdf', 'first', complevel = 9 )

sampleDF2['totalCites2'] = sampleDF2['totalCites2'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))

sampleDF2.to_hdf( 'pandasNumpy.hdf', 'first', complevel = 9 )
```

For convenience, here is a colab notebook which has this code

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DjiPsN3MbRWP6NnJwvaAhzy66FNbPVA8

Edit:

As hpualj mentioned, Pandas uses Pytables not h5py, so it looks like the question should be how to use vlarray, which is how pytables store variable length arrays.

Comment: `to_hdf` uses `pytables` to interface with `HDF5`, not `h5py`.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57729777/901925

Comment: So it looks I should be looking into vlarray, which is how pytables store variable length arrays

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question? I would also like to be able to save ragged tensors using pandas.

Comment: A few solutions. You could save them as text, and then convert to numbers when you open. Or you could put them all in one column, then have a another column to indicate which class the datapoint belongs to, and when you open the file, you can either use pandas or numpy to stack all rows with that particular collumn type